Exercise 2.2 In Stanley's Algebraic Combinatorics
This is Exercise $2.2$ In Stanley's Algebraic Combinatorics. I don't have much work to show because despite being stuck on this problem for a long time, I haven't got a clue how to start.

$\mathcal{C}_{n,k}$ is a subgraph of the $n$-dimensional cube $\mathcal{C}_n$, which is bipartite, so $\mathcal{C}_{n,k}$ is bipartite as well. Therefore, it makes sense that its eigenvalues occur in $\pm \lambda_i$ pairs. As the graph is $k$-regular, $\pm k$ must be two of the eigenvalues. I'll also tried considering $A^2$. The matrix has $k$ along its diagonals and $(A^2)_{uv} = 1$ iff $u$ and $v$ have the same weight and the Hamming distance between $u$ and $v$ is $2$. However, beyond that I'm stuck.
The book gives Exercise 9.9 as a hint, which is:

I've verified that $\mathcal{C}_{n,k}$ is vertex transitive, but I don't know how to apply the lemma.
